# How to initialize value to function whose return type is boolean?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I want to initialize `true` for `checkForBST(node* rootptr)` function. What should i do? I know variable initialization but I always get confused in function initialization. Below is my `checkForBST(node* rootptr)` function:

```
bool checkForBST(node* rootptr){
        queue <node*> Q;
        int parent;
        int child1;
        int child2;
        node* parentadr;
        Q.push(rootptr);
        do{
          parent=Q.front()->data;
          parentadr= Q.front();
          if(Q.front()->left !=NULL) {child1= Q.front()->left->data;} else{child1=-1;}
          if(Q.front()->right !=NULL) {child2= Q.front()->right->data;} else{child2=-1;}
          Q.pop();
          if(child1>child2){return false;}
          if(parentadr->left != NULL){Q.push(parentadr->left);}
          if(parentadr->right != NULL){Q.push(parentadr->right);}
        }while(!Q.empty());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but if you want to initialize the return type for the function to return 'true', then you would just create a local function variable, initialize it to true, and return that variable at the end.

```
bool checkForBST(node* rootptr) {
    bool returnVal = true;

    ....

    return returnVal;

}
```

The title of your question sounds more like you're trying to assign a variable to a function (function pointer variable). To do that, you would do something like this:

```
bool checkForBST(node* rootptr) { 
    ...
} 

void (*my_variable)(node*) = &checkForBST;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response:) It worked. Actually my code format was:  bool checkForBST(node* rootptr) {
    
   .......................        if( ...)      {return false}
   
}. but the condition is I cannot add return true otherwise it will return but I have to return only when if condition is true. So, I have to set by default value as true and I was trying to initialize function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'return true;' statement at the end:

```
bool checkForBST(node* rootptr){
    queue <node*> Q;
    int parent;
    int child1;
    int child2;
    node* parentadr;
    Q.push(rootptr);
    do{
        parent=Q.front()->data;
        parentadr= Q.front();
        if(Q.front()->left !=NULL) {child1= Q.front()->left->data;} else{child1=-1;}
        if(Q.front()->right !=NULL) {child2= Q.front()->right->data;} else{child2=-1;}
        Q.pop();
        if(child1>child2){return false;}
        if(parentadr->left != NULL){Q.push(parentadr->left);}
        if(parentadr->right != NULL){Q.push(parentadr->right);}
    }while(!Q.empty());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks:) It worked. But can we actually initialize function who have return types such as bool, int, double?

Comment: The same way. Simply use the value of type of the function/method return, like 'return 0;', return '0.0' - of course it not need to be 0, can be any value of type which the function/method returns. And, in the fact it is not initialization, it should be treat as value returned in case that the function flow reached the end of fuction code.